# Keyboard driver corrupts after installing update KB4565503

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard

I installed update [KB4565503](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4565503/windows-10-update-kb4565503) and my keyboard driver corrupted with [error code 39](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310123/error-codes-in-device-manager-in-windows). Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plausible that the keyboard driver is using a call which has been deprecated in that KB, or the values the call are expecting are invalid. The best course of action here is to reach out to the keyboard vendor and inform them of the issue, so they can update their driver.

From the release note text on that KB

> Updates to improve security when using input devices (such as a mouse, keyboard, or stylus).

This is most likely the root-cause.

Comment: Luckily I have Auslogics Driver Updater and updated my driver to that of Fujitsu's. Thank god for this amazing software.